# How to fix this Exception and Type Error? (Django)

Tags: python, html, django

I was following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vM9mcWr1RMg&list=PLzMcBGfZo4-kQkZp-j9PNyKq7Yw5VYjq9&index=8) tutorial by Tech with Tim, but suddenly after adding a few lines of code I only gett type errors or exception errors when I try to see my webpage.

My code:

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from .models import Item, ToDoList
from .forms import CreateNewList
# Create your views here.

def index(response):
    return HttpResponse("<h1>Hello, world!</h1>")


def item_by_id(item_id, id=None):
    item = Item.objects.get(pk=item_id)
    return HttpResponse(f"Item: {item.title}, published on {item.datetime_found}")


def home(response):
    return render(response, "myapp/home.html", {})


def base(response):
    return render(response, "myapp/base.html", {})


def itemlist(response, list_id):
    ls = ToDoList.objects.get(id=list_id)
    return render(response, "myapp/itemlist.html", {"ls": ls})


def create(response):
    if response.method == "POST":
        form = CreateNewList(response.POST)  # Takes POST and uses data for form
        if form.is_valid():  # is_valid() checks class-fields for valid input
            n = form.cleaned_data["name"]  # Clean and un-enc data, specify field "name"
            t = ToDoList(name=n)  # Use data to create new ToDoList
            t.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect("itemlist/%i" % t.id)  # Redirect to page that shows the list
    else:
        form = CreateNewList()
    return render(response, "myapp/create.html", {"form": form})
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.forms import model_to_dict
from django.utils.timezone import now

class Item(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)  # Short description of the item
    datetime_found = models.DateTimeField(default=now, blank=True)  # Date and time of when the item was found


def items():
    res = []
    for i in Item.objects.all():
        res.append(model_to_dict(i))
    return res


class ToDoList(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class ListItem(models.Model):
    todolist = models.ForeignKey(ToDoList, on_delete=models.CASCADE)  # related to ToDoList
    text = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    complete = models.BooleanField()  # Boolean says if we're completed list item

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('item/<int:id>', views.item_by_id, name='item_by_id'),
    path('home', views.home, name='home'),
    path('base', views.base, name='base'),
    path('itemlist/<int:id>', views.itemlist, name='itemlist'),
    path('create/', views.create, name='create'),
]
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms


class CreateNewList(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(label="Name", max_length=200)  # Label is the text that shows before the input-box
    check = forms.BooleanField()  # Boolean check button
```

My HTML-files:

base.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>{% block title %}My Webite{% endblock %}</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="content", name="content">
        {% block content %}
        <h1>Welcome to my website!</h1>
        {% endblock %}
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

home.html

```
{% extends "myapp/base.html" %}

{% block title %}
Home
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<h1>Home Page</h1>
{% endblock %}
```

itemlist.html

```
{% extends "myapp/base.html" %}
{% block title %}View List of Items{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>{{ls.name}}</h1>
    <ul>
        {% for i in ls.listitem_set.all %}
            {% if i.complete == TRUE %}
                <li>{{i.text}} - COMPLETE</li>
            {% else %}
                <li>{{i.text}} - INCOMPLETE</li>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endblock %}
```

create.html

```
{% extends "myapp/base.html" %}
{% block title %} Create new List of Items {% endblock %}
{% block content %}
Create Page
<form method="POST" action="/create/">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form.as_p}}
    <button type="submit", name="save">Create New</button>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

This worked perfectly before I added the create-parts (create-view and create.html). But now I get errors even when I try to enter the pages that one would think would be un-affected by the new code.

When I run the server and try to enter `http://127.0.0.1:8000/base/` or `http://127.0.0.1:8000/home/` or `http://127.0.0.1:8000/create/`, it works.

But when I try to go to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/itemlist/1` or another number, I get this error:
[image: ERRORMESSAGE 1]

And when I try to go to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/item/1` or another number, I get this error:
[image: ERRORMESSAGE 2]

I have tried altering the functions to have arguments like `item_by_id(item_id, id=None):` instead of `item_by_id(response, item_id,):` but then the error message just alters from the first error-picture to the last one.

What am I missing here? How can I fix this? All help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

whatever argument you pass to you view function should be the same argument you pass to that's view corresponding url pattern

```
def itemlist(response, list_id):
    ls = ToDoList.objects.get(id=list_id)
    return render(response, "myapp/itemlist.html", {"ls": ls})
```

in the view function above you passed the argument as **list_id** but in your url pattern you passed it in as **id**...this is what is leading to the conflict...resolve this and it should work just fine

**Solution**

#view_function

```
def itemlist(response, list_id):
    ls = ToDoList.objects.get(id=list_id)
    return render(response, "myapp/itemlist.html", {"ls": ls})
```

corresponding url pattern
...

```
path('itemlist/<int:list_id>', views.itemlist, name='itemlist'),
```

And for the Second Error...you forgot to the pass the required request parameter(which you use as response in your code) to the function...the item_id is not neccesary..so remove it and change its reference to just **id**

```
def item_by_id(response, id=None):
    item = Item.objects.get(pk=id)
    return HttpResponse(f"Item: {item.title}, published on {item.datetime_found}")
```

Comment: This worked for when I enter the url for a list directly. But when I try creating a new list by going to  ´127.0.0.1/create/´, and press "Create New" it tries to go to the url ´http://127.0.0.1:8000/create/itemlist/23´ as if it thinks I have over 20 lists created, when I only have created 6 or 7. I tried creating some lists through the admin-page, do you think maybe that has something to do with it?

Comment: I entered ´http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/´ and created lists through there. And now, when I try to enter ´/itemlist/1´ I get the first list, ´/itemlist/2´  displays the second list, ´/itemlist/3´ through ´/itemlist/8´ displays the third list, and ´/itemlist/9´ through ´/itemlist/20´ displays the list I created through admin,

Comment: is that an issue?

Comment: I thought the number would match the id of the list-object. But this makes it seem like I have over 20 list-objects. Or have I misunderstood something

Comment: Oh oh i see the issue....reread my answer for the updated solution

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235547/discussion-between-brian-obot-and-mampenda).